# How to provide a counter example to sequence limit question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Suppose $(a_n)^∞_{a=1}$is a convergent sequence and $a_n \in [a, \infty)$ for all n.  Is it necessarily true that the limit of  $(a_n)^∞_{a=1}$  lies in
$(a,∞)$ if $a_n \in (a, \infty)$ for all $n$? Prove or provide a counterexample.

So if the limit doesn't lie in $(a,∞)$, then the limit must lie in $(-∞, a]$? I guessing it would be $a$?  I don't understand how can all the terms lie in a certain interval but the limit somehow is in the other interval?

Comment: No, it is not true. Here is a very simple example: $a_n = a +\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: For your second question the answer is "Yes". If the limit does not belong to $(a,\infty)$, then $a_n \rightarrow a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\forall n) \: a_n \geq a \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \geq a$$
and,
$$(\forall n) \: a_n > a \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \geq a$$

An example where $(\forall n) \: a_n > a$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = a$ is the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$. Clearly $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ but $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$.

"I don't understand how can all the terms lie in a certain interval but the limit somehow is in the other interval?" ---- Limits of sequences from a closed set will always lie in that closed set, but limits of sequences from an open set will lie in the closure of that set.